# Pegar dados do modal no Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho uma lista de clientes na tela do responsável, caso ele aperte para negar o cliente, abre um modal com o campo Motivo para ele preencher. Quero pegar o que foi digitado nesse campo e salvar na tabela Historico_perfil no banco. Porém, não é um form, como faço?

Além disso, preciso pegar para salvar também o id do cliente negado e o do responsável logado que negou

views.py

```
def usuarios_autorizar(request, value=None, user_id=None):
    user = Perfil.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    title = "Usuarios nao autorizados"
    grupo_responsavel = Grupo.objects.filter(responsavel=user.id)
    usuarios = Perfil.objects.filter(grupos__in=grupo_responsavel, is_staff=False)
    context = {'lista_usuarios': usuarios}

    return render(request, 'usuarios_autorizar.html', context)
def negar(request, item_id):
    # para negar
    user = User.objects.get(id=item_id)
    user.is_staff = False
    user.save()
    # historico
    historico = Historico_Perfil.objects.create()
    quem = User.objects.get(id=item_id)
    print(quem.id)
    historico.usuario = quem.id
    historico.data = datetime.now()
    historico.acao = "Negado"
    historico.save()
    return redirect("/cadastro/quantities")
```

models.py

```
class Historico_Perfil(models.Model):
    acao = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    motivo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    data = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

html

```
 <table class="striped" id="cadastrados">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th>Ramal</th>
                <th>Grupo</th>
                <th>Autorizar</th>
                <th>Negar</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>


            {% for item in lista_usuarios %}
            <tr>

                <td>{{ item.first_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.telefone }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.ramal }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.grupos }}</td>
                <td id="autorizado"><a href="{% url 'cadastro:autorizar' item.id %}"
                                       class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue">
                    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                </a>
                </td>
                <td id="negado"><a href="#modal1"
                                   class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue">
                    <i class="large material-icons">clear</i>
                </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </li>

            <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Motivo</h4>
             <textarea id="motivo" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="{% url 'cadastro:negar' item.id %}" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-blue btn-flat blue">Enviar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: se você vai ter uma comunicação dessa maneira, você teria duas formas: usar sim um form dentro do modal, ou então fazer uma chamada AJAX. A segunda maneira trás a questão de ter de usar JavaScript. Na primeira maneira, seria apenas um form com um botão, e nele você passaria as informações necessárias para processar dentro de sua view.

Comment: Sem utilização de um form, você poderia tentar usar um requisição AJAX.